# Accept Trade Offer from Steam using Web-API & Java

Tags: java, steam-web-api

I have a Java Steam Trade Bot that reads through pending Trade Offers from Steam and declines them based on requirements. I am using the official Web API (using the API Key from http://steamcommunity.com/dev/apikey) to communicate requests to Steam. The variable `trade` is from my own API Interface (which I have debugged and works for declining offers).

`SteamPlug.steamRequest(method, query);` is just a basic HTTP requester:

```
public static String steamRequest(String method, String query) {
    try {
        URL obj = new URL(query);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

        con.setRequestMethod(method);

        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();

        if (responseCode != 200 && responseCode != 201) {
            return "ERR" + responseCode;
        }

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();

        return response.toString();
    } catch (MalformedURLException | ProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // Ignored
    }

    return null;
}
```

This is how it declines trade offers:

```
SteamPlug.steamRequest(
          "POST",
          "http://api.steampowered.com/IEconService/DeclineTradeOffer/v0001/?key=" 
          + SteamPlug.API_KEY + "&tradeofferid=" + trade.getTradeOfferId()
);
```

What I am trying to do is accepting trades as well. I have tried this:

```
SteamPlug.steamRequest(
          "POST",
          "https://steamcommunity.com/tradeoffer/" + trade.getTradeOfferId() + "/accept?key="
          + SteamPlug.API_KEY
);
```

But I receive a `411 Length Required` response.

**I believe I can accept offers by using a Steam session authentification, but is it possible to accept a Trade Offer using only the user's Web-API key?**

Answer (score 2):

Have you read steam API docs? There's no trade accept function, so I assume you can't accept trades via API.
Your option is to check SteamBot's (though it is written in C#) trade functions  and think about straight http requests to steam site (with proper steam authentication I believe). I myself writing a bot currently, and single thing that stops me now - accepting trades.

Comment: Yes I have read these docs in the past. However, I believe another way around it would be for the bot to send offers instead, although this is not documented as well.

Comment: Well botting is against Steam ToS (at least market part) so I highly doubt API will allow sending or accepting trades. Plus API mainly supposed for extensions and stuff, it's insecure to allow accepting trades this way.

Answer (score 0):

[Java Steam Trade Library](https://github.com/wonderf/steam-trade-library)
Developed Lib for send and accept trades in Steam

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).